# Typescript infered type cannot be used

Tags: typescript

I was trying to attach types on function library of javascript.

But when I tried to implement function 'go1' which apply fn(any function) on 'then' chain after target has been evaluated if target is instanceof Promise, I got a problem

In my opinion there is nothing wrong, there is enough clues to conclude type of fn.

```
function go1<T, K>(target:T, fn:T extends Promise<infer Val> ? (val:Val)=>K : (val:T)=>K):
    T extends Promise<any>? Promise<K>: K {
    return target instanceof Promise ? target.then(fn) : fn(target) as any
}
```

Although function 'go1' with string argument works, but when I call 'go1' with Promise argument like beneath

```
const b = go1("anyString", x=>x.Lowercase()) // works; return "anystring"

const promiseString = Promise.resolve("string")
const c = go1(promiseString,x=>x.Lowercase()) // emit error
```

typescript emit complier error on promiseString

```
Argument of type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
_.ts(111, 19): Did you forget to use 'await'?
```

Mayber there is somthing problem on conditional type ot Typescript.
When I change conditional statement to any from T, it also works.
but I cannot check type of argument on fn

```
fn:T extends Promise<infer Val> ? (val:Val)=>K : (val:any)=>K
const c = go1("string",
               x=>x.Lowercase() //x is any, cannot suppose type)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, zerkms. Actually I cannot understand why you said this function expects a string. ''go1' function takes any argument on target position.

Comment: I have tried this piece of code on stackblitz but it doesn't throw any error

Comment: thanks for your reply, @Hallah, I will try

Comment: which angular version you are using? and node version?

Comment: WTF, there is no error on stackblitz. Maybe there is something problem on my project, Thanks @Hallah

Comment: node is 13.7.0 and typescript is 3.8.3

Comment: try node 12 as it's stable version

Comment: Oh,  I have found a problem on my tsconfig.json. I don't know why, but strict options makes problem. I have changed my strictFunctionTypes option from true to false. Now it works.. Thanks @Hallah. Actually I have spent whole times of day to solve to problem, believing I got some misunderstanding on advanced type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Hallaha, I have found a problem on tsconfig.json.
strictFunctionTypes option makes problem. After changing it from true to false, code works.

```
  "strictFunctionTypes": false /* Enable strict checking of function types. */,
```

Comment: Then you should upvote my comments :) for appreciation

Comment: Sorry, upvote required more than 15 reputations, but it't only 11 on me. Actually I have just register account for this  question.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAczgRgDwBUA0iBKAfABRQCGATsgKZQBciAChXALYwDO12hewYDYgA8GWAJSIAvIQJiGzNp25EAUKEiwEKdNjxFSlGvUS5E-QSJMTpshvjXho8JKkyn95KrXkt2XHogAPiZ8AojCotYy+HJMvkoYREEEiADeKoiZiBS0IBRInkaIMGAc5JDUcMBxilyIAPyIhbQAdFAAFtRgxPwSDPwGXlBiKgC+KioQCGWIAEZS2mjEAERkYACeAMpQFCXIy3hCUjJCbXAAMnAA7tQUAMJkXMRiI5PTUIgADvFc27tgyAWCj81BaOQ4cAANgA3agrMr-fYjKalD4QBauYjfWrUP57Q7HRCnKAXa63B5PF5AA

Comment: thanks for replay, @AlekseyL. It seems to be better. I will try